# rails check_box_tag + label_tag

Tags: checkbox, ruby-on-rails-3.2, label, slim-lang

In my view I have a checkbox and a label.
I am using SLIM so the code is

```
= check_box_tag 'All Products'
= label_tag 'All Products'
```

And the equivalent HTML generated is

```
<input id="All_Products" name="All Products" type="checkbox" value="1">
<label for="All_Products">All products</label>
```

Even though the "input id" and the "label for" both have the same value i.e "All_Products" , I am unable to select the checkbox when I click on the label.

Is there anything I am missing out ?

I want to select the checkbox when I click on the label.

Answer (score 1):

`All Products' is probably not the best name to use for the element id/name (even if it does get converted), maybe try something a bit cleaner like

```
= check_box_tag 'all-products'
= label_tag 'all-products', 'All Products'
```

that should produce

```
<input id="all-products" name="all-products" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label for="all-products">All Products</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

This actually should work. 
However there could be one of the problems:

- the id is not unique on the page;
- label is not clickable, because of styling